# Redirecting output from the remote server

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to run this below command from a centos local machine on a remote ubuntu server. but it not happening.

`ssh -t hostname su - -s /bin/bash bar "/home/bar/get_list.sh >> output-1"`

When running this above command we get this error

```
Connection to 192.11.13.2 closed.
```

The script is located at remote machine & we want to redirect the output to the local machine.

If we run this its asking me the passowrd & showing the output data

```
ssh -t HOSTNAME su - -s "/bin/bash USERNAME '/path/to/script.sh'"
```

But when running with redirection `>>` its not asking me the passowrd and showing connection closed

**Troubleshooting**

I did some troubleshooting here I was trying to redirect with `>>` but when I changed it to `>` its is creating the file `output-1`.

Here is the output of that file

```
cat output-1
Password:



su: Authentication failure
```

Answer (score 0):

This `Connection to 10.11.143.72 closed.` *as a case*, means you command executed successfully but the file is created in `remote-host` instead of in local.

please bring the redirection output outside of the command to log the result in local host.

```
ssh -t hostname su - -s /bin/bash bar "/home/bar/get_list.sh" >> output-1
```

Also it's better to use the command as like below syntax (I generalized the command):

```
ssh -t HOSTNAME su - -s "/bin/bash USERNAME '/path/to/script.sh'" >> inlocal.log
```

Comment: Previously i was just getting the error there was no file on remote host, But the command which you suggested is also not working.

Comment: its not asking me for password

Comment: the file is generating where you login to remote host with `USER@HOST`, if it's `root` the file is under `/root` directory, if it's a user it's under `/home/USER/` directory.

Comment: Actually with your command it will work but password prompt is not displayed because of which the connection is closed.

Comment: Try to rest sudo timestamp_timeout with `sudo -k` and try again, also once check the file generating in `/home/bar` because that connection close coming when you successfully connected to remote host, invoked script and if the script produces result then the result is written in local host and then exit from ssh

Comment: I used locate command to the check the file existence on the remote machine, but there isn't any file there. Actually the `Password:` prompt is not visible on the screen & it seems like its hanged. Need to troubleshoot that.

Answer (score 0):

Your edited question as it currently stands still includes the redirection inside the double quotes, which would force it to create the file on the wrong server, if it worked.

However, I'd propose you investigate setting the SUID bit on the script file.  Assuming you have the rights to set that on the Ubuntu target, it would mean it gets run as root without you having to actually log in as root.

I don't exactly understand why your current solution isn't at least putting 'Enter password:' into your output file.  It may be detecting it's not talking to a live tty, although if it can do that through a ssh connection and on to another box, I'm impressed.

Comment: I am logged in as a common user, which is getting changed to a normal user not root. 
without the redirection `>> output_file` if we run the command its showing the output on local system.

Comment: Yes, that's why you're using su to get root access.  The redirection, if you've got it inside the quotes as in your example, will mean everything will get put inside the file on your server, as you've seen.  It seems to be detecting it's going into a file so you won't be able to respond, and just reporting 'authentication failure', and then closing the connection.

Comment: FWIW I just tried 'ssh user@hostname -C randomexecutable >> local.log' and it resulted in a local file with output from the remote server.  Note I have no quotes around the redirection except those here to show you where the command starts and finishes.